Soft-close drawer guides won't retract without continuous pressure
I'm building a workbench with 15 drawers. The drawer guides seem to be stiff in all cases, even without a drawer, it takes continued pressure to keep them moving.  However, when you get to the soft-close point, they suck in the rest of the drawer guide nicely.
Most of the drawers turned out fine; the soft-close feature works: get it to that point, let go, and it keeps going in.  Two drawers are giving me trouble though.  If I keep gentle pressure THROUGH the soft-close point to the end (sometimes having to push on one side or the other), they close fully.  But if I let go after the soft-close begins, they stop about half way in.
The troublesome drawers are quite square; diagonals are less than 1 mm from each other. I measured the gaps between drawer and cabinet on the installed drawers. The two sides all total 25.5-26.5 mm, slightly more than 1 inch, on all the drawers, including the troubled ones.
The middle cabinet with the problem is a bit narrower in the middle than top and bottom; I guess the plywood was warped.  But I carefully cut each drawer's front and back to fit the space available for that drawer.
How can I troubleshoot this?  In the photo, the problem drawers are the middle column, bottom two.


Welcome to WSE. My first impression is that the width of the track is not correct, and the slides are rubbing on the inside or outside of the base tracks. If the tracks are too wide you can narrow it by providing shims at the points where they are screwed to the cabinet panels. If the tracks are too narrow, then you have to cut a recess on at least one side to recess the tracks and provide a wider opening.

The usual suspect with anything like this would be binding as I'm sure you know, but the drawer guides apparently being stiff in all cases does suggest it's perhaps primarily them or entirely them (and with no mention a brand or type can we presume they're not high-end?) The only way to be sure is to remove them and run them by themselves; you'll immediately get the answer. If they do run fine then it's some aspect of the install that you have to troubleshoot — and there is abundant help online about that (including among manufacturer's own documentation).

Since you're an experienced SEer Jim, I'll tell you I've VTC and I downvoted for the first-listed reason in the popup, no apparent research effort.

@Graphus I don't know what you mean by VTC and a "popup", but of course I did research.  That's why I already pointed out that the guides close fine without the drawers, the drawers are square, and the gaps between drawer and cabinet are in the same range as drawers that close fine.  The guides are full-extension, soft-close, Tobinice brand.  They seem high quality.  One idea I need to check is maybe the rear of the cabinet is not the same width as the front.

I've experienced similar problems with a different brand of full extension slides.  Mine called for a tolerance of +1/32 inch and zero in the other direction on each side so that really makes a drawer tolerance between zero and 1/16 inch., I forget which one direction was zero.  The drawer went in OK for awhile.  A few years later it was getting stiff to close.  The problem was that the back of the drawer had changed so as to be beyond the acceptable tolerance.

VTC = vote to close. As for research, what do you mean of course you did.... the body of the Q shows no evidence of it — SE requires that you explicitly say, so respondents don't need to be inferring things. As per the Help, the asker is supposed to mention (and ideally link to when it's online) at least a few of the things found in their research, see Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards? for starters. This is so that, for example, someone doesn't waste time linking something already read.

Re. the popup, if you are not on mobile, hovering the cursor over the vote arrows gives a popup with a brief summary of why one should upvote or downvote. Since your Q did not list any research it fits [one of the] requirements for downvoting.

The problem was that the back of the cabinet was slightly wider than the front, and exceeded the maximum tolerance of the guides for the two drawers.  The Tobinice installation video basically says the cabinet inside width must be 26.0 to 26.8 mm larger than the drawer width.  That's less than a millimeter wiggle room!
The back of the cabinet for the two drawers was 27.5 and 28.5 mm wider than the drawers.  That's 1.1 mm larger than the ideal for one and 2.1 for the other; only 0.7 and 1.7 mm more than the maximum tolerance.
I was able to shim the back of the cabinet members slightly and bend the attachment tabs; then the drawers closed as expected.
